# flex item ignoring align-content property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following:

```css
main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  }

.content-container {
  padding: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 74px;
  flex-basis: min-content;
  }
```

```html
<main>
<div class="content-container">
     <div>Exercitationem officiis, quod. Culpa deserunt et nisi perspiciatis quisquam tempora tempore voluptates?
      Assumenda commodi distinctio fugiat illo in ipsam maiores minus nam ratione rem, saepe soluta tempora, vero.
      Quisquam, voluptatum!
    </div>
    <div>Autem cumque debitis deleniti dicta doloremque ea est ex, harum magni natus omnis placeat provident recusandae
      saepe sapiente, ut voluptas voluptate, voluptatibus? Dolore dolores iure necessitatibus non obcaecati saepe sequi!
    </div>  
</div>
</main
```

I would like to have the `.content-container` always centered regardless of the screen size. But the issue is that the `.content-container` div always gains a height of `100vh` (regardless of not having a defined height). I tried setting `flex-basis` but it has no effect.

If I manually set the `height` to for example 100px, the content will just overlap.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `flex: 0` should do it, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single-line flex container (`flex-wrap: nowrap`), use `align-items` for cross-axis alignment.

In a multi-line flex container (`flex-wrap: wrap`), use `align-content`.

In this case, because there is only one flex line (which occupies the full-height of the container), use `align-items: center` on the container, or `align-self: center` on the item.

`align-items` goes on the flex container. It sets the default `align-self` for all items.

`align-self` goes on individual flex items. It overrides `align-items` set by the parent for that particular item.

Here's a more complete explanation:

- [How does flex-wrap work with align-self, align-items and align-content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613359/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
.content-container {
    align-self: center;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-items` to distribute items along the cross-axis of their container:

```
main {
      align-items: center;
}
```